# Redux - Unable to use dispatch to call action inside of axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am new to react and redux, this is my first attempt at using a redux action to call an API with it returning a list of products which I can then add to the redux store for me to use in any component. So far the API call is  working, and returns a list of products when I add a console.log in the then response, however when I use dispatch to call the next action which sets the type I receive the error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function".

Here is my Fetch.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as React from "react";

export function loadProducts() {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get(getApiHost() + 'rest/productComposite/loadProductsWithImages/' + getId() + '/ENV_ID').then((response) => {
           dispatch(getProducts(response.data.productDtos));
        })
    }
}

export function getProducts(productDtos) {
    return {
        type: 'product',
        productDtos: productDtos
    }
}

function getId() {
    return params().get('id');
}

function getEnv() {
    let env = params().get('env');
    if (!env) return 'prod';
    return env;
}

function getApiHost() {

}

function params() {
    return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
}
```

and my reducer.js file:

```
const initialState = {
    loaded: 'false',
    productDtos: []
}

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'product':
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: 'true',
                productDtos: action.productDtos
            }
        default:
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: 'false',
                productDtos: action.productDtos
            };
    }
}

export default productReducer;
```

and my index.js file:
(there is lots of messy code in this file which is why i am trying to convert the project into redux)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import allReducers from './components/reducers'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store = {store}>
          <App/>
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and my app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import PageHero from './PageHero';
import Products from './Products';
import ProductDetail from "./ProductDetail";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./PrivacyPolicy";
import LicenceAgreement from "./LicenceAgreement";
import {loadProducts} from "./Fetch";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.cartProductsRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            loadedShopConfig: false,
            loadedLogo: false,
            productView: false,
            products: null,
            logoUrl: null,
            lAView: false,
            pPView: false
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.changeBack = this.changeBack.bind(this)
        this.addToCart = this.addToCart.bind(this)
        this.lAViewChange = this.lAViewChange.bind(this)
        this.pPViewChange = this.pPViewChange.bind(this)


    }

    params() {
        return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    }

    getId() {
        return this.params().get('id');
    }

    getEnv() {
        let env = this.params().get('env');
        if (!env) return 'prod';
        return env;
    }

    getApiHost() {

    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        // Display fallback UI
        this.setState({hasError: true});
        // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
        console.log('error', error);
        console.log('info', info);
    }

    changeBack() {
        this.setState({
            productView: false,
            lAView: false,
            pPView: false
        });
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState({productView: true});
        this.setState({selectedProduct: event})
    }

    addToCart(product, quantity) {
        console.log('cartProductsRef', this.cartProductsRef);
        if (this.cartProductsRef.current) {
            this.cartProductsRef.current.addToCart(product.entityInstanceId.id, quantity, product);
        }
        this.setState({})
    }

    lAViewChange() {
        this.setState({lAView: true});
    }

    pPViewChange() {
        this.setState({pPView: true});
    }


 loadShopDetails() {
        this.setState({...this.state, isFetching: true});
        fetch(this.getApiHost() + 'rest/shopComposite/' + this.getId() + '/ENV_ID')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log('Shop Details Function Results ', responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    shopConfig: responseJson.shopConfig,
                    logoUrl: responseJson.logoUrl,
                    currencyCode: responseJson.currencyCode,
                    website: responseJson.website,
                    twitter: responseJson.twitter,
                    facebook: responseJson.facebook,
                    instagram: responseJson.instagram,
                    linkedIn: responseJson.linkedIn,
                    youTube: responseJson.youTube,
                    loadedShopConfig: true,
                    loadedLogo: true
                });
            })
        this.setState({...this.state, isFetching: false});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadShopDetails();
        this.props.dispatch(loadProducts());

    }

    render() {
        let displayProduct;
        const {lAView} = this.state;
        const {pPView} = this.state;
        const {productView} = this.state;
        const {shopConfig} = this.state;
        const {logoUrl} = this.state;
        const {selectedProduct} = this.state;
        if (productView && !lAView && !pPView) {
            displayProduct = <ProductDetail
                product={selectedProduct}
                addToCart={this.addToCart}
            />;
        } else if (!lAView && !pPView) {
            displayProduct =
                    <Products
                        shopConfig={this.state.shopConfig}
                        productSelectedHandler={this.onChange}
                    />;

        }

        return (

            <div id="page">

                <ErrorBoundary>


                    <p>{this.state.productView}</p>

                    <Header
                        logoUrl={this.state.logoUrl}
                        itemsInCart={this.state.itemsInCart}
                        changeBack={this.changeBack}
                        currencyCode={this.state.currencyCode}
                    />


                    {!productView && !lAView && !pPView && this.state.loadedShopConfig ?
                        <PageHero shopConfig={this.state.shopConfig}/> : null}

                    {displayProduct}

                    <Cart id={this.getId()}
                          apiHost={this.getApiHost()}
                          ref={this.cartProductsRef}
                          currencyCode={this.state.currencyCode}
                    />

                    {lAView ? <LicenceAgreement
                        shopConfig={this.state.shopConfig}
                    /> : null }

                    {pPView ? <PrivacyPolicy
                        shopConfig={this.state.shopConfig}
                    /> : null }


                    {this.state.loadedLogo ? <Footer
                        logoUrl={this.state.logoUrl}
                        lAChange={this.lAViewChange}
                        pPChange={this.pPViewChange}
                        twitter={this.state.twitter}
                        facebook={this.state.facebook}
                        instagram={this.state.instagram}
                        linkedIn={this.state.linkedIn}
                        youTube={this.state.youTube}
                        website={this.state.website}

                    /> : null}

                </ErrorBoundary>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps() {
    return loadProducts()
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps me, its probably a quick fix of something that I doing wrong, although I have read many articles and watched many videos and cannot find an immediate problem.

Comment: How do you dispatch `loadProducts` action?

Comment: I have attached the app.js file above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you dispatch an action in connected component. Notice that `mapStateToProps` is the first argument you pass into `connect` function, even if it returns an empty object:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { loadProducts } from './path/to/actions'

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadProducts();
  }

  render() { ... }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = { loadProducts };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you didn’t connect loadProducts